# What is :XML ON in T-SQL query to export data into XML using SQLCMD?

Tags: xml, t-sql, bcp, sqlcmd, sql-server-2008

On this [blog post about exporting data to XML](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-xml.htm#SQL%20Server%20Data%20Export%20to%20XML%20using%20SQLCMD) with TSQL using BCP or SQLCMD I came across this line of code:

```
:XML ON

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo02.ExcelTest
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('doc')
```

I tried using it in the sql query and then triggering via sqlcmd in a batch file, it did return a correct xml file. Without the `:XML ON` it returns strange values as described on the webpage.

Strangely enough, SSMS (2008) shows incorrect syntax when parsing or executing the query.

What does `:XML ON` do and how to use it? And why doesn't SSMS recognize the line of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is explained in this MSDN page (search for ":XML"): [sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

That pages states:

> XML output that is the result of a FOR XML clause is output,
>   unformatted, in a continuous stream.
>
> When you expect XML output, use the following command: **:XML ON**.
>
> > *Note*
> >     **sqlcmd** returns error messages in the usual format. Notice that
> >     the error messages are also output in the XML text stream in XML
> >     format. By using **:XML ON**, **sqlcmd** does not display informational
> >     messages.
>
> To set the XML mode off, use the following command: **:XML OFF**.
>
> The GO
>   command should not appear before the XML OFF command is issued because
>   the XML OFF command switches **sqlcmd** back to row-oriented output.
>
> XML
>   (streamed) data and rowset data cannot be mixed. If the XML ON command
>   has not been issued before a Transact-SQL statement that outputs XML
>   streams is executed, the output will be garbled. If the XML ON command
>   has been issued, you cannot execute Transact-SQL statements that
>   output regular row sets.
>
> > *Note*
> >     The **:XML** command does not support the SET STATISTICS XML
> >     statement.

In SSMS, even if you enable "SQLCMD Mode" (in the Query menu), you will get the following error trying to use the `:XML` command:

```
Scripting warning.
Command Xml is not supported. String was not processed.
```

This is most likely due to this particular command not being needed within the context of the Query Editor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, explains most of it, but do you put :XML ON in the first line of the sql query or in the batch file with the sqlcmd?

Comment: All SQLCMD commands need to be in the SQL script. On the same MSDN page that I linked to in the answer, search for "sqlcmd Commands". You should read at least the first 5 bullet points (just passed "Be aware of the following") as they will give additional context. Of course, it would probably be best to read that entire section :).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can export XML using SQLCMD:

1. Create the script to generate XML:

   ```
   SET @sqlSelect = ':XML ON '+@NewLineChar+';WITH Header AS (  SELECT ( SELECT '''+@contactPerson+''' ContactPerson FOR XML PATH('''')...
   ```

   Here, add `:XML ON` then `NewLineCHAR (CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10))`
2. Change `''` into `''''`:

   ```
   SET @sqlSelect= REPLACE(@sqlSelect,'''','''''')
   ```
3. Create a temp table with a single field as `VARCHAR (2000)` and insert into this field your new string (`@sqlSelect`)
4. Create a temp file on disc with with what you inserted into your temp table:

   ```
   SET @commandline = 'sqlcmd -S . -E -h-1  -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT  
   CAST([field] as nvarchar(1500)) FROM [temptable]" -o "tempfile.sql"  -w 1500 '
   EXEC @result = master..xp_cmdshell @commandline
   ```
5. Create the XML using this SQL file:

   ```
   SET @commandline = 'sqlcmd  -i tempfile.sql -o ResultFile.XML 
   EXEC @result = master..xp_cmdshell @commandline
   ```